# sed will not remove single quote

Tags: linux, sed

I've tried several different formats, but none of them are working. Any assistance would be appreciated:

```
[root@home:/home/users/jlefler]$ sed "s/[',#,`,@]//g" stage_data.out > stage_data
> ^C
[root@home:/home/users/jlefler]$ sed "s/[\',#,`,@]//g" stage_data.out > stage_data
> ^C
[root@home:/home/users/jlefler]$ sed "s/[#,`,@,\\']//g" stage_data.out > stage_data
> ^C
```

Comment: You don't need commas to separate items in `[]` classes, that will add a literal comma to be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by `sh`, not by `sed`.

Double quotes still allow certain special characters to have special meanings, such as `$` and, in this case `` ` ``.

This works:

```
echo "a'b'c" | sed -e "s/['#\`@]//g"
```

Or you could avoid all shell-related problems by sticking your patterns in a file and using `sed -f`

Answer (score 2):

Let's ask [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
sed "s/[',#,`,@]//g" stage_data.out > stage_data
            ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this backtick expansion.
```

The backtick is the problem, not the single quote. Just escape it:

```
sed "s/[',#,\`,@]//g" stage_data.out > stage_data
```

Here's an example of this in action:

```
$ echo "'#@foo" > stage_data.out
$ sed "s/[',#,\`,@]//g" stage_data.out > stage_data
$ cat stage_data
foo
```

Comment: backtick isn't the problem - expression works without the single quote included.

Comment: @user3299633 Doesn't work for me with backquote but no single quote. But you haven't pasted any code that uses that case.

Comment: @user3299633 Make sure you are able to tell the difference between the single quote `'` and the backtick `\``. They look very similar -- nearly identical in some fonts -- but they are not the same character. The backtick slants backwards and is absolutely the cause of your problem, while the single quote is straight and does not matter here. I added an example. Please try copy-pasting it and seeing for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
sed "s/[',#,\`,@]//g"
```

Comment: It's better to explain *why* your answer works, not just paste the code.